# Prevent Google maps JS executing multiple times caused by Rails Turbolinks

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, google-maps, turbolinks

I'm currently working on Rails app that is getting the following error:

> You have included the Google Maps API multiple times on this page.
>   This may cause unexpected errors.

After a little research I discovered that Turbolinks was causing the problem. When the `link_to` is clicked all of the DOM elements created by Google maps are retained within the DOM. When a new page is rendered another set of Google Map DOM elements is added causing duplicates and the error.

I could fix this very quickly by simply adding `'data-no-turbolink' => true` to my `link_to` but this defeats the purpose of using Turbolinks as it forces a refresh.

I'm wondering if there's a potential workaround to stop this duplication without turning Turbolinks off?

map.js:

```
var initMap = function initMap() {

  if (typeof mapLatLng != "undefined") {

    // we can use this to set the map zoom
    // in different places. 
    // use: window.setZoom = 12;
    if (typeof setZoom ==! "undefined") {
      var mapZoom = setZoom;
    } else {
      var mapZoom = 14;
    }

    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
      zoom: mapZoom,
      center: mapLatLng,
      disableDefaultUI: true,
      scrollwheel: false
    });

    var markerSVG = {
      path: 'M1152 640q0-106-75-181t-181-75-181 75-75 181 75 181 181 75 181-75 75-181zm256 0q0 109-33 179l-364 774q-16 33-47.5 52t-67.5 19-67.5-19-46.5-52l-365-774q-33-70-33-179 0-212 150-362t362-150 362 150 150 362z',
      fillColor: '#f32e74',
      fillOpacity: 1,
      strokeWeight: 0,
      anchor: new google.maps.Point(870,1650),
      scale: (0.02, 0.02)
    };

    var mapMarker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: map.getCenter(),
      map: map,
      icon: markerSVG,
    });
  }
}
```

view:

```
<% if @job.address.latitude && @job.address.longitude %>
  <%= javascript_tag do %>
    window.mapLatLng = {lat: <%= @job.address.latitude %>, lng: <%= @job.address.longitude %>};
  <% end %>
  <% content_for :js do %>
    <script async defer src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?signed_in=false&callback=initMap"></script>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 12):

Instead of `<script async defer src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?signed_in=false&callback=initMap"></script>` make it a regular `<script></script>` tag and add the following below your initMap function:

```
if(window.google){
  initMap();
} else{
  $.ajax('https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?signed_in=false&callback=initMap', {
    crossDomain: true,
    dataType: 'script'
  });
}
```

If you aren't using jquery then just use XMLHttpRequest instead.

Answer (score 6):

Adding `data-turbolinks-eval="false"` to the script tag will tell turbolinks not to re-evaluate it.

```
<script async defer src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?signed_in=false&callback=initMap" data-turbolinks-eval="false"></script>
```

See https://github.com/turbolinks/turbolinks#working-with-script-elements

Worked in our case, where all our script tags were in `<head>` as per turbolinks docs.

Answer (score 3):

Try this too....

`google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'turbolinks:load', initialize)`;

And remeber, all google script have to stay after Turbolink, like this:

```
= javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload'
= javascript_include_tag 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload'
= javascript_include_tag 'gmap', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload'
```

See more at: https://github.com/turbolinks/turbolinks

Answer (score 1):

I had faced the same problem, unfortunately this might be of no help to you after so many months.

I moved:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?libraries=places"></script>
```

in **head** tag after <%= csrf_meta_tags %>, and moved the:

```
<%= javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
```

after **/body** tag.

**By doing so I resolved this issue:**

You have included the Google Maps API multiple times on this page. This may cause unexpected errors.

Added data-no-turbolink to the link in navigation bar, the page where I have map. This helped me keep using turbolinks in all pages without that error and as well as let me generate the map when that page was accessed.

Comment: Still have the above issue the above does not resolve this

Answer (score 1):

adding `data-turbolinks-eval=false` to the script tag solves the problem

See the docks of the turbolinks gem for more details
https://github.com/turbolinks/turbolinks-classic#evaluating-script-tags

Comment: this removes "error" but , does not load maps API's every time.you can see it working on page refresh, but not on page load

Comment: @AnujaJoshi I have the same problem; the map does not show up on page load, but only on page reload. Did you manage to solve it?