# Google Maps on a ruby on rails site

Tags: ruby-on-rails, google-maps

I'm using Google Maps on a ruby on rails site. Code is below:

```
<div id="map" style='width: 1170px; height: 500px;'></div>
<script>

var map;

function initialize() {
      map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'));

      var json = <%=raw @places.to_json %>;
      var data;
      var service = new google.maps.places.PlacesService(map);
      var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();


      if (json.length == 0) {
        map.setCenter({lat: 40.736, lng: -73.991});
        map.setZoom(11);

      } 
      else {


          for (var i = 0, length = json.length; i < length; i++) {
              data = json[i].google_key; 
              if(data != null) {

                service.getDetails({placeId: data},function(results, status){
                    if (status == google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OK) {
                        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                            map: map,
                            place: {
                                placeId: results.place_id,
                                location: results.geometry.location
                            },

                        });
                        bounds.extend(results.geometry.location);
                        map.fitBounds(bounds);
                    }
                }); 
              } 
          }
      }
      googleAutocomplete();
}


function googleAutocomplete() {
    var input = document.getElementById('place_name');
    var autoComplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input);
    autoComplete.addListener('place_changed', function() {
        var place = autoComplete.getPlace();
        document.getElementById('place_name').value = place.name;
        document.getElementById('place_google_key').value = place.place_id;

    });
}



</script>


<script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyA68X13MKpg02y8ZdpKtOUociJqhAg8QyY&libraries=places&callback=initialize" async defer></script>
```

I get the following error:

```
You have included the Google Maps API multiple times on this page. This may cause unexpected errors.
```

I would appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your issue is related to turbo-links.  Try adding this line to your script tag and see if the error goes away.

```
data-turbolinks-eval="false"
```

So your new script tag should look like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyA68X13MKpg02y8ZdpKtOUociJqhAg8QyY&libraries=places&callback=initialize" data-turbolinks-eval="false" async defer></script>
```

Let me know if that helps.

Comment: I just noticed that now when I load the page, it won't work the first time I load it -- if I refresh all is well. Any idea why this is happening?

Comment: We are pretty busy here at work today and I don't have much time.  If you read the question asked by this individual, you should be able to figure it out(https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33115375/prevent-google-maps-js-executing-multiple-times-caused-by-rails-turbolinks).  Also if you're not using turbo-links then try removing it from your `application.js` file and see if it works on page load.

Comment: No worries -- figured it out. Thanks!